# Execute Bash commands Python way

Tags: python, bash

I am currently executing bash commands manually, by entering in shell in the python code.

How would one do this in the pythonic way?

i am currently using `os.system` function to execute commands like;

```
os.system('sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php')
os.system('sudo apt-get update')
os.system('sudo apt-get install php7.0 php5.6 php5.6-mysql php-gettext php5.6-mbstring php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-xdebug libapache2-mod-php5.6 libapache2-mod-php7.0')
os.system('sudo a2dismod php7.0 ; sudo a2enmod php5.6 ; sudo service apache2 restart')
```

Comment: Use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: This problem has already been solved here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python).

It is recommended to use `subprocess` module instead. `os.system` has been depreciated in favour of `subprocess`. For more information see [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) documentation.

```
import subprocess

command = 'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php'
process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
```

Comment: An response like this needs to go in as comment.

Comment: @Anil_M oh, ok sorry

Comment: There's also the convience function in python 3 for getstatusoutput which is pretty nice.

   ` status, output = subprocess.getstatusoutput('cmd')`